# Exclude elements from a list of objects

Tags: r

I have a list of elements

```
all<- list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

The list includes objects and non existing elements (a is an object and b does not exist).

```
all
Error: objeto 'all' no encontrado
```

Because some elements in the list do not exist.

I would like to find an expression as to exclude from the list non objects and obtain a list that includes only those objects that exist. I have tried with the expression

```
exists(all)
Error en exists(all) : objeto 'all' no encontrado
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you ever successfully created the `all` object?  The first command you list should have failed if you were missing any of those objects, so `all` shouldn't actually exist.

Comment: Understood, so I should eliminate prior to creating the list the non existing elements. In a prior example I eliminated the elements that were non existant and then created the list but wanted to kknow if it was possible do it in reverse.

Comment: You can create a list with the names of the objects you want, and then populate a list with the objects that exist, but yes, otherwise it isn't possible AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
LL <- as.character(substitute(c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)))    #where a,b,c, etc are your objects
L2 <- LL[which(sapply(ll,exists))]    #checks to see if they exists
final_list <- sapply(L2,get)    #creates list of those objects that do exist
```

e.g.

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c('t','r','e')
d<-c('gfd','dgdf','gd')
f<-c(2,45,6)
l2<-as.character(substitute(c(a,b,c,d,e,f)))
> l2
[1] "c" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
GOOD<-l2[which(sapply(l2,exists))]
> GOOD
[1] "c" "a" "b" "c" "d" "f"
sapply(GOOD,get)
$c
function (..., recursive = FALSE)  .Primitive("c")

$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] "t" "r" "e"

$c
function (..., recursive = FALSE)  .Primitive("c")

$d
[1] "gfd"  "dgdf" "gd"  

$f
[1]  2 45  6
```

Comment: +1! I guess you need the `[-1]` when creating `LL` to avoid listing the `c` too. And, also,  you could wrap all this in a function like:
`list2 = function(...)`

`{`
 `env <- parent.frame();`
 `LL <- as.character(substitute(c(...))[-1]);`
 `L2 <- LL[which(sapply(LL, exists, where = env))];`
 `final_list <- sapply(L2, get, pos = env);`
 `return(final_list);`
`}`
. And, an example, `list2(a, b, c, d, e, f)`

Comment: sure =) just thought I'd throw the basics out there and let the experts take over from there =)